# Flutter Same Device ID on Different Devices

Tags: android, flutter

I'm using device_info_plus library for Device uniqid.
Everything working fine till.

But now I'm facing weird issue.

1. All device id has been changed.
   Like first they are getting as 240a75fXXXXXXXXX like this.
   Now they are getting as RKQ1.21XXXXXX.XXX like this.
2. Also same device id founded on different device.
   Same device id has been get from 5 different device.

This is issue is only on Android Devices. Everything working fine on iOS.
I'm using

```
device_info_plus: ^8.0.0
```

```
await _deviceInfo.androidInfo.then((value) {
      device_imeino = value.id;
    });
```

Whats wrong??

Comment: Before asking on StackOverflow, please research your problem. The plugin is open source: https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/tree/main/packages/device_info_plus so always check issues. Possibly related: https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/issues/1341

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try out with this code :

> device_info_plus: ^3.2.1

```
String? deviceId = '';

getDeviceID() async {
    final DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfoPlugin = DeviceInfoPlugin();
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfoPlugin.androidInfo;
      deviceId = androidInfo.androidId ?? '';
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      IosDeviceInfo iosInfo = await deviceInfoPlugin.iosInfo;
      deviceId = iosInfo.identifierForVendor ?? '';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

androidID is removed from device_info_plus since v4.1.0. Check the [changelog](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/blob/b9951b7e99d7ffc495a886def9154eef5cb1ab9d/packages/device_info_plus/device_info_plus/CHANGELOG.md#410).

[android_id](https://pub.dev/packages/android_id) package is recommanded to get the correct androidId.